# How to Calculate which Cashback that use on the Order in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Cashback background:
Cashback is like cash but only can be used on our platform. Cashback can be got by ordering by using a promo, referring another user to join our platform and etc.
example:
User A ordered 10000 with cashback 2% on 1 Jan 23, so he will get 2% * 10000 = 200 cashback amount means the table will show

| get_date | get_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-23 | 200 |

after getting the cashback, users can use it to pay for something that they order and combine it with real cash if the cashback amount is not enough.

---

I want to calculate from the order whether they are using the cashback that they get or not with the condition cashback will be expired 7 days after they get it and they only can use the amount they get and can’t be more of that so the user need to add more cash to checkout the order.

please help to create the query to calculated that with 2 tables name **get_cashback** this table is use to know when and how much cashback amount that the user get and it has 2 field name **get_date** and **get_amount**. the other table name **order** is used to know when and how much their order amount and it has 2 field names **order_date** and **order_amount**

I want the result to be in 5 fields:

- order_date = date of user ordering
- order_amount = how much their order amount
- type = type the user uses the pay their order can be 'new' or 'cashback' where new means he needs to add more cash to the order
- get_date = date of the user gets the cashback
- amount = amount of the user use/spend the cashback on this order

**Example 1:**
table **get_cashback**

| get_date | get_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-23 | 10000 |
| 2-Jan-23 | 20000 |
| 3-Jan-23 | 10000 |

table **order**

| order_date | order_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 3-Jan-23 | 5000 |
| 4-Jan-23 | 10000 |
| 5-Jan-23 | 40000 |

Result

| order_date | order_amount | type | get_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-Jan-23 | 5000 | cashback | 1 jan 23 | 5000 |
| 04-Jan-23 | 10000 | cashback | 1 jan 23 | 5000 |
| 04-Jan-23 | 10000 | cashback | 2 jan 23 | 5000 |
| 05-Jan-23 | 40000 | cashback | 2 jan 23 | 15000 |
| 05-Jan-23 | 40000 | cashback | 3 jan 23 | 10000 |
| 05-Jan-23 | 40000 | new | null | 15000 |

explanation:
on 1 jan 23 the user get 10000 cashback, when the user order 5000 on 3 jan 23, it will use 5000 from it with 5000 leftovers. on 4 jan 23, the user order 10000, it will use 5000 leftovers on cashback 1 jan 23 and 5000 amount from 2 jan 23 while this makes cashback 2 jan 23 have 15000 leftovers. on 5 jan 23 the user order 40000, it will use 15000 from leftover cashback 2 jan 23, 10000 cashback from 3 jan 23 and because the order 40000 and the cashback leftover is 35000, the user need to add 15000 cash

**Example 2:**
table **get_cashback**

| get_date | get_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-23 | 10000 |
| 2-Jan-23 | 5000 |

table **order**

| order_date | order_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 3-Jan-23 | 5000 |
| 4-Jan-23 | 2000 |
| 9-Jan-23 | 10000 |

Result

| order_date | order_amount | type | get_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-Jan-23 | 5000 | cashback | 1 jan 23 | 5000 |
| 04-Jan-23 | 2000 | cashback | 1 jan 23 | 2000 |
| 09-Jan-23 | 10000 | cashback | 2 jan 23 | 5000 |
| 09-Jan-23 | 10000 | new | null | 5000 |

explanation:
on 3 jan 23, they order 5000 and use cashback from 1 jan 23 5000 that makes cashback 1 jan 23 5000 leftovers and ok 4 jan 23 the user order 2000 and will use cashback from 1 jan 23 again that will make cashback 1 jan 23 3000 leftovers but on 9 jan 23 the cashback from 1 jan 23 already expired on 8 jan 23 or 7 days after they get the cashback so we can’t use the 3000 leftovers and that makes 9 jan 23 order will use 5000 from 2 jan 23 cashback and the user need to add 5000 new or cash

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem that I would work on if you could add more on a description of how all the cash back works in human terms.

Comment: @DaleK already change the tag to google-big-query, thanks!

Comment: hi @shawnt00, I just added the description of the cashback, is it enough to explain it? thanks

Comment: If your issue has not been resolved, can you provide more details about your requirements by clarifying the doubts mentioned by shawnt00 in his answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first stab at this. While I don't think you can avoid an iterative solution this should be pretty efficient. This uses a working/temp table to accumulate the output.

Since I don't have BigQuery I've done this on SQL Server. It should translate very cleanly should you want to use it.

There would also be a few points worth clarifying. I think you probably want to tie back point to an identifier rather than a date. You probably also want to do this on a per user basis. It's also not clear whether cashback should become available for immediate use and things of that nature. And presumably you don't get an extra 2% for using the cashback previously earned.

I think what I've done here is very adaptable to tweaking some of the rules. Think of this as a proof of concept.

```
create table worktable (tx_type char(1) not null, tx_dt date not null, tx_amt int not null, cashback_dt date null, order_dt date null, order_amt int null);
insert into worktable(tx_type, tx_dt, cashback_dt, order_dt, tx_amt)
select 'P', cashback_dt, cashback_dt, null, cashback_amt from cashback union all
select 'X', dateadd(day, 7, cashback_dt), cashback_dt, null, -cashback_amt from cashback;

declare @r int = 1;
while @r > 0 begin

with next_order as (
    select top 1 * from orders where order_dt >
        (select coalesce(max(tx_dt), '20000101') from worktable
         where tx_type in ('D', 'N'))
    order by order_dt
), entries as (
    select *,
        sum(amt) over (order by dt, tx_type, amt desc) as cum_amt
    from next_order as o cross apply (
        select 'D' as tx_type, w.cashback_dt, sum(w.tx_amt)
        from worktable as w
        where w.tx_type in ('P', 'D', 'X') and w.tx_dt < o.order_dt
        group by w.cashback_dt
        having sum(w.tx_amt) > 0
        union all
        select t, d, a from (values
            ('N', o.order_dt, 0)
            -- this would apply 2% back on full order amount.
            -- is that correct or would it only apply to the new cash portion?
            ,('P', dateadd(day, 1, o.order_dt),  cast(floor(o.order_amt * 0.02) as int))
            ,('X', dateadd(day, 7, o.order_dt), -cast(floor(o.order_amt * 0.02) as int))
            ) r(t, d, a)
        ) as w(tx_type, dt, amt)
), allocated as (
    select *,
        lag(cum_amt, 1, 0) over (order by dt, tx_type, amt desc) as lag_cum_amt
    from entries cross apply (values (
        case when tx_type = 'D' and cum_amt < order_amt then -amt
             when tx_type = 'D' then cum_amt - amt - order_amt
             when tx_type = 'N' and cum_amt < order_amt then order_amt - cum_amt 
             when tx_type in ('P', 'X') then amt
             else null end
    )) as v(tx_amt)  
)
insert into worktable (tx_type, tx_dt, tx_amt, cashback_dt, order_dt, order_amt)
select
    tx_type,
    case when tx_type in ('X') then dt else order_dt end as tx_dt,
    tx_amt,
    case when tx_type in ('D', 'X') then dt
         when tx_type in ('P') then order_dt end as cashback_dt,
    order_dt,
    case when tx_type in ('D', 'N') then order_amt end as order_amt
from allocated
where (cum_amt < order_amt or lag_cum_amt < order_amt and cum_amt >= cum_amt)
    or tx_type in ('P', 'X');

set @r = @@rowcount;
end

select
  order_dt as order_date, order_amt as order_amount,
  case tx_type when 'D' then 'cashback' when 'N' then 'new' end as "type", 
  cashback_dt as get_date, abs(tx_amt) as amount
from worktable
where tx_type in ('D', 'N')
order by
    tx_dt, case tx_type when 'X' then 1 when 'D' then 2 when 'N' then 3 when 'C' then 4 end;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ummeOl5v